# Manage Queue System in multiple Threads in java

Tags: java, queue, message-queue

I have a Queue of request. There are two threads. In on thread i am adding the items to queue and second thread basically get the requests from queue list and execute them. So second thread wait for 1st thread to put some request in the list. I am doing so in a while loop. I don't think this is a best way to do it. It is CPU intensive. I can think of a way to notify the 2nd thread whenever I add a request. but there can be problem that the request may not execute successfully so I have to ask 2nd thread again to execute the request.
so is there any way you can think will work ?

Comment: See http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/blocking-queues.html

Comment: i think i will go for Blocking Queue . but one question is when you call pop on blocking queue it should wait for element to insert. but as in documentation it is written that it will return null if no element is available. so this gonna be a problem?

Comment: On `BlockingQueue` you must to use `take`. This method *blocks* the thread waiting for the element in the queue. See http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the available blocking queues in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

The busy waiting is indeed not recommended (unless you want to use your computer for heating).

Comment: They use basically a more "smart" approach (which can for example indeed be implemented with the wait/notify technique). Instead of waiting in a loop for the queue becoming non-empty (and using a lot of cpu utilization during this so called busy waiting), they sleep and are notified once new elements are put in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Semaphores` to solve this problem.

The second thread, which is the worker thread will wait on the semaphore. Every time the 1st thread pushes new task info onto the `Queue` structure, it will also post to the `Semaphore` so now the second thread can safely go and execute.

This may also need some synchronization along the way if there are multiple reader/writer threads.

Comment: but what is the way to wait for 1st thread (producer) to put some elements in the Queue List ? as i am using while loop which is for sure not a best way

Comment: The semaphore will intially be set to 0, so the second thread will wait/block without doing a while-loop wait. Every time the 1st thread pushes data to the queue, it will increment the semaphore. Since the semaphore count will now be > 0, the second thread can execute.